# Wildcard to route to a controller

Tags: php, asp.net, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I am absolutely novice with Laravel and I am currently learning the routes feature of the Framework.

I want to know if it is possible to do like we can do with ASP.NET that is to redirect to a Controller written in the URL.

Actually, to do something like:

```php
<?php

Route::get('/{CustomController}/{Action}', function ($controller, $action) {
    return controller($controller, $action);
});
```

Where `CustomController` is the controller which will run the request to the view `Action`

With ASP.NET Core, it is something like:

```asp
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with routes in laravel the format is this:

```
Route::get('/custom-controller', 'CustomController@index');
```

If you are using the standard method names in your controller such as `index()`, `store()` etc

you can use resource instead and it will automatically build up all your routes:

```
Route::resource('/my-route', 'CustomController');
```

If you then do `php artisan route:list` you will see laravel has automatically added all the standard routes for your controller.

Comment: yes but... no.
The goal is to have 1 route for X controllers where the controller is choosen IN THE URL and can be used as a variable is the routing module.

Comment: As far as I'm aware that isn't something that is built into `laravel`, if you need that functionality you will need to extend the router.